# Pick random element from collection. Can it inherit from Random class?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need something that generates random words from given set instead of numbers.

```
String[] words = {"this","is","an","example"};
while( true )
  System.out.println( random.nextFromArray(words) );
```

Can I just inherit from Random? Is it permitted to inherit from this class? Or any other java.util.Something?

```
class RandomArray extends Random {
    public <T> T nextFromArray( T[] array ) {
        return array[ nextInt(array.length) ];
    }
 }; RandomArray random  = new RandomArray();
```

Comment: Uh, why do you want to do that? There are many ways to do what you want which do not require that you extend `Random`.

Comment: It just came up this way, I needed this method inside other method (not to clutter my surrounding class definition), and instead of Runnable I wrote local class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Random class is not final - it is permitted

There are some subclasses you can look at:
[SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), [JVMRandom](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/JVMRandom.html) and [ThreadLocalRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)

But in your case you can use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) or go with what Ted Hopp suggests.

Comment: What about `SecureRandom`? By the way, you should only do this if you need a new type of random number generation.

Comment: @tbodt Thanks for mentioning it! I just wanted to say that extending a class is legal. For the author's case it is not needed, agreed.

Answer (score 4):

Turn the `String[]` into a list, so that `Collections.shuffle` can be used to randomize the list's order.  Then retrieve the first element in the `List<String>`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"this","is","an","example"};
    int x = 0;
    while(x < 2)
    {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(words);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
        x++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use a `Random` object directly:

```
Random rand = new Random();
String[] words = {"this","is","an","example"};
while (true) {
    System.out.println(words[rand.nextInt(words.length)]);
}
```

You can make a generic method if you need the flexibility to deal with arrays of different types, but you still don't need to subclass `Random`.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I just inherit from Random? Is it permitted to inherit from this class?

It is permitted.  But it is not the right thing to do.

Inheritance is for situations where you want something that behaves like the class you are extending ... and some more.  But you (apparently) don't need your `RandomArray` class to behave like a random *number* generator.  What you actually need is a helper method like this:

```
     public static <T> T nextFromArray(Random random, T[] array) {
         return array[random.nextInt(array.length)];
     }
```

There are two reasons for doing it this way, not your way:

- This way allows you to use other kinds of random number generator that extend `Random`.
- Your way has the conceptual problem that `RandomArray` is a complete misnomer.  A `RandomArray` instance is not an array at all.  Instead, it is a random number generator with an extra method for selecting an element from a *separate* array.

If you were to design a real random array class, it would look something like this:

```
    public class <T> RandomArray {
        private T[] array;
        private Random random;

        public RandomArray(Random random, T[] array) {
            this.random = random;
            this.array = array;
        }

        public T randomElement() {
            return array[random.nextInt(array.length)];
        }

        public T get(int index) {
            return array[index];
        }

        public void set(T value, int index) {
            array[index] = value;
        }
    }
```